# How to convert an Info.plist file from mac os project to iphone project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, plist

I am developing an app for the iPhone OS devices, and am using a third-party engine which is not well documented but I've made great progress with it anyway.

The problem:

The engine's developer strongly urges extending from the existing template projects bundled with the engine, but the engine's Info.plist files are Mac OSX project Info.plist files.

This is an iPhone engine, and so I cannot understand why the Info.plist file is structured to take keys for Mac OS apps, but that's how it is.

I did a FileMerge comparison to ensure there was nothing within the file itself that defined its use for one OS or the other, so I guess it's defined somewhere in the project settings.

**Edit -**

Opening the plist file in Xcode or Property List Editor and then trying to add a key such as "Icon already includes gloss and bevel effects" will not work in this iPhone project because it is not in the list.  However, "Cocoa Java Application" and others are available!

Comment: ? Mac plist and iPhone plist share the same format.

Comment: OK, you mean Info.plist.

Comment: sorry, I haven't spent much time using plist files, except the Info.plist file.  
It just confuses me... i've copied the file, renamed it to the same as the project, renamed it to the same as the folder, ensured it was == another file that DOES have "Icon already includes gloss and bevel effects"... Therefore I assume it's some external associated property... somewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta information for iPhone/iPad projects is stored in **/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneInfoPlistStructDefs.xcodeplugin**, assuming you took the installation defaults -- ymmv.  I successfully merged some information into there from **/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/InfoPlistStructDefs.xcodeplugin**.  For some reason, the iPhone plugin didn't have all the human-readable names in the "Documents" category.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some information I collected from 
[iPhone dev center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009248) within the About Information Property List Files chapter:

> Important: The property list editor in
>   Xcode displays human-readable strings
>   (instead of the actual key name) for
>   many keys by default. To display the
>   actual key names as they appear in the
>   Info.plist file, Control-click any of
>   the keys in the editor window and
>   enable the Show Raw Keys/Values item
>   in the contextual menu. When typing
>   key names yourself, you should always
>   type the actual key name.

This is useful for future reference, the recommended behaviour for updating the Information Plist files...

Additionally, my research has led me to believe the pre-loaded human-readable key names CANNOT be recreated unless someone creates a new project.  It is stored somewhere in the meta information of the project itself and the Property List Editor can interpret that, not to mention Xcode itself.  So, until someone decides to interpret that meta info, it's just a matter of using the recommended approach as mentioned above.